# Loop with repeated exception catching

Tags: java, loops, nullpointerexception, goto

I need to do something like this:

```
while(prot.getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA(start) == null) start++;
```

But because `prot` throws `NullPointerException` I cannot loop like this. How can I create a loop that catches the `NullPointerException`, increments start, and executes `getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA` again ,and so on, until `getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA` will not throw `NullPointerException` ("it's ok" that the loop have the possibility to be infinite).

I never used `goto` and I don't even know how to use is, but will something like this will work somehow?:

```
        *here*
        try{
            prot.getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA(start);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            start++;
            goto *here*
        }
```

Comment: Just to add clarity - In Java `goto` doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `goto` - there is no implemented `goto` in Java anyway.  You can just put the `try/catch` in the loop. The loop can continue when the exception is caught, one thing has nothing to do with the other.

```
int start = 0;
boolean isNotNull = false;

while (!isNotNull) {
    try {
        prot.getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA(start);
        isNotNull = true;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        start++;
    }
}
```

I have written this with the assumption that you have no say over how `getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA()` is implemented.  However, if you do control this method, or know the person who does, make sure it does not throw a `NullPointerException` when passed an index to an empty location - that is not good API design.  It should instead return something that indicates that the location is empty.  [There is a lot of lively disagreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java/271874#271874) over whether that something should be a `null` or a non-null object indicating emptiness; but either way, don't throw an exception.

Comment: +1 - Although, you might want to remove your other obsolete answer.

Comment: Oops, not sure how I managed to make 2.  Thanks for catching that - deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent `NullPointerException` from being thrown in the first place. A `NullPointerException` usually indicates there's a bug in your code.

```
while (prot != null && prot.getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA(start) == null) start++;
```

If `getProcessedTranscriptPositionFromAA` itself may throw a `NullPointerException`, you should fix that method too.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you write **throws NullPointerException** on same line of class name.For handling multiple NullPointerException in single class.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a wrapper Method which catches the NPE for you.

Something like:

```
public static boolean getSomething(ProtClass prot){
    try{
        //do something
        return true;
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use this function in the while expression.